# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x714b52a000

Tags: android, android-ndk

I applied the NDK to my project.

I found a solution that was supposed to fix the error by giving read permission to that memory, but this didn't work for me.

I gave read access to the memory I wanted to access using 'mprotect'.

Also, this problem is not consistent and probable because I tried various test cases; but they all got different results.

My test device is Galaxy 21.

Here is my error:

```
************************************************************************************************
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x714b52a000
     x0  ffffffffffffffff  x1  0000000000000008  x2  0000000000000001  x3  0000000000000069
     x4  0000000000000021  x5  8080800000000080  x6  fefeff70a93f3eff  x7  7f7f7f7fff7f7f7f
     x8  000000714c060840  x9  000000714b529ffe  x10 00000000003a565e  x11 00000000000000ff
     x12 00000000003a565e  x13 0000000000000000  x14 00000072c0154110  x15 ffffffffffffffff
     x16 0000007524677f30  x17 0000007524607f78  x18 00000071aa400898  x19 00000073a023a1a0
     x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000007218f2bac0  x22 0000000000000000  x23 00000073a023a250
     x24 0000007218f2bac0  x25 0000000000000003  x26 000000000000000b  x27 00000071aa404000
     x28 00000071aa400db0  x29 00000071aa400590
     lr  000000714b935670  sp  00000071aa400430  pc  000000714b935684  pst 0000000020001000
************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Without access to your code, all we can infer is that your code contains a buffer overflow or something similar. Signal 11 is a segmentation fault.

Comment: @tripleee: Most likely yes. However keep in mind that SIGSEGV may also be raised if attempting to access addresses that are mapped but protected, with the signal handler's purpose being to lift the protection. So most likely OP is dealing with an out-of-bounds access our invalid pointer dereference, but may be something else.